# How I can add pagination in swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have spend so much time to find a solution with the documentation from Firebase without any success. I using Swift 5.3 and Firestore and have the following code:

```
func readFlights() {
        Spinner.startAnimating()
         let myquery = db.collection("flight").limit(to: 25).whereField("Userid", isEqualTo: userID).order(by: "DateDB", descending: true)
            .order(by: "Start", descending: true)
         myquery.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    self.prefixArray.append(document.get("Prefix") as! String)
                    self.dateArray.append(document.get("Date") as! String)
                    self.startArray.append(document.get("Start") as! String)
                    self.stopArray.append(document.get("Stop") as! String)
                    self.landingArray.append(document.get("Landing") as! String)
                    self.takeOffArray.append(document.get("Takeoff") as! String)
                    self.flightTimeArray.append(document.get("FlightTime") as! String)
                    self.engineTimeArray.append(document.get("EngineTime") as! String)
                    self.idArray.append(document.get("id") as! String)
                    self.destinationArray.append(document.get("Destination") as! String)
                    self.originArray.append(document.get("Origin") as! String)
                    self.informationArray.append(document.get("Addinfo") as! String)
                    self.rulesArray.append(document.get("VFRIFR") as! Int)
                    self.pilotCopilotArray.append(document.get("PilotoCopiloto") as! Int)
                    self.engineArray.append(document.get("MnteMlte") as! Int)
                    self.dayNightArray.append(document.get("DayNight") as! Int)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.tabelView.reloadData()
                self.Spinner.stopAnimating()
                }
            }
        }
```

working fine but I need to include in this code pagination. That means when I received the first 25 records from Firestore and I slip down in the list with my finger so I want after the latest record he load 25 records more and show them.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a document cursor that is an instance property of the view/view controller:

```
var cursor: DocumentSnapshot?
let pageSize = 25 // for convenience
```

Second, apply the page size to the query:

```
let myquery = db.collection("flight").limit(to: pageSize).whereField("Userid", isEqualTo: userID).order(by: "DateDB", descending: true).order(by: "Start", descending: true)
```

Third, whenever you receive a snapshot from Firestore, update the cursor at some point in the return (ideally, after you've unwrapped the snapshot and before you've parsed the documents):

```
func getData() {
    myquery.getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        ...
        if snapshot.count < pageSize {
            /* this return had less than 25 documents, therefore
               there are no more possible documents to fetch and
               thus there is no cursor */
            self.cursor = nil
        } else {
            /* this return had at least 25 documents, therefore
               there may be more documents to fetch which makes
               the last document in this snapshot the cursor */
            self.cursor = snapshot.documents.last
        }
        ...
    })
}
```

Finally, whenever the user scrolls to the bottom, fetch another page using the cursor:

```
func continueData() {
    guard let cursor = cursor else {
        return // no cursor, exit
    }
    myquery.start(afterDocument: cursor).getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        ...
        // always update the cursor whenever Firestore returns
        if snapshot.count < self.pageSize {
            self.cursor = nil
        } else {
            self.cursor = snapshot.documents.last
        }
        ...
    })
}
```

For a fluid user experience, you will need to greatly refine this code, but this is the foundation from which you can paginate Firestore. You can also paginate in Firestore using a document offset (instead of a document cursor) but this is to be avoided (refer to documentation for the reasons).

Answer (score 0):

By using UITableViewDelegate, u can call the function. Each time when you scroll to the bottom, it will check the max of your limit and if the condition is true, then fetch data again.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastItem = self.array.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastItem {
        if limit < max_limit {
            limit += 25
           //Get data from Server
           readFlights(limit:Int)
        }
    }
}
```

The max_limit means the total amount of limits, usually, it returned by server in meta

Answer (score 0):

You can use awesome solution from: https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

For your example:

```
tableView.addInfiniteScroll { (tableView) -> Void in
    readFlights("offset if need")
    tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
}
```